# Salesforce - Restricting picklist values on profile

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, process-builder, administration

**Dear Salesforce Gurus**,
I have been searching for this all over the internet. I haven't found the answer
I am looking for a way to restrict some picklist values to be appearing in a profile without creating a new record type.
**scenario**: user1 is assigned to the sales manager profile and user2 is assigned to the Sales director profile. Both these profiles are assigned to the same page layout and record type. **The objective is to let Sales manager to see fewer opportunity statuses than the Sales director**.  **

> How can I achieve this without creating a new record type?

**

*Why avoid the creation of a new record type  -- because Creating a record type would disrupt the process because picklists values are referenced in the third-party CPQ tool. So I can't afford to create a new record type for the object.*

Comment: If it is ok to create a new field then create a picklist field called user role and add the picklist values like Sales Manager & Sales Director. After that create a field dependency between the created field & status field.

Comment: One option is to create a validation rule (the options would still be visible, but you can block the user of the profile Sales manager to select some options.

Comment: @Jefersen Chaves ..The validation idea is good and it solves half of the problem but this is not accepted by the client as they want to hide the some of the picklist values  from the Sales manager. Thanks for the kind effort Jeferson!

Comment: @AnkaiahBandi , Thanks for your kind effort. The picklist values are already created. I have been trying to achieve this with validation but not getting it.

Comment: @shaileshkumar, What you have tried with validation rule?